# SQL COUNT Rows Result in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently use this to count all the number or rows in a table and it works well for what i need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS STCount 
  FROM  (SELECT Distinct DPoint, RNum 
           FROM ECount  
          WHERE DType = 'STR' AND Month(EDate) = '07') AS rows
```

The only issue i have is i have to repeat this statement a lot while just changing a few things each time. I would like to Union these Selects but have the result show in a seperate column, the example below works getting the results but puts them all in the same column. Any ideas how to have them show in their own column one for STCount and NCCount?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS STCount 
  FROM (SELECT Distinct DPoint, RNum 
          FROM ECount  
         WHERE DType = 'STR' AND Month(EDate) = '07') AS rows 
 UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NCCount 
  FROM (SELECT Distinct DPoint, RNum 
          FROM ECount  
         WHERE DType = 'NCD' AND Month(EDate) = '07') AS rows
```

result would be,

```
STCount NCCount
  100     202
```

Comment: could you please give the current result and expected result in table format so that we can be more clear about question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do selects in the `select` clause and don't need a `from`.

```
select (select count(1)
        from  (select distinct DPoint, RNum 
               from ECount
               where DType = 'STR' 
                 and Month(EDate) = '07') as x
       ) as rows1,
      (select count(1)
       from  (select distinct DPoint, RNum 
              from ECount  
              where DType = 'NCD' 
                and Month(EDate) = '07') as x
      ) as rows2;
```

Comment: Richard, Is there a way to set the column names with this method?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, replace `rows1` and `rows2` with the names you need.

Comment: @Ryan Now had a chance to test: fixed up the SQL (SQL Server would have given an error) to name the inner inner (`select distinct`) queries. The naming of columns is working here.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a CASE :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (CASE WHEN DType = 'STR' THEN (1)  ELSE NULL END) AS STCount,
    COUNT (CASE WHEN DType = 'NCD' THEN (1)  ELSE NULL END) AS NCCount
    FROM (Select Distinct DType, DPoint, RNum From ECount WHERE Month(EDate) = '07') as rows
```

Comment: and you can put a condition of the month in WHEN if you have different months like this:  WHEN DType = 'STR' and Month(EDate) = '07' and add EDate in the FROM (Select Distinct EDate ,DType, DPoint, RNum ....

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS STCount 
          FROM (SELECT Distinct DPoint, RNum 
                  FROM ECount  
                 WHERE DType = 'STR' AND Month(EDate) = '07')) AS STCount
       , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NCCount 
           FROM (SELECT Distinct DPoint, RNum 
                   FROM ECount  
                  WHERE DType = 'NCD' AND Month(EDate) = '07')) AS NCCount
```

Comment: RealCheeseLord, I tried this but i still get (No Column Name)

Comment: I changed the brackets, maybe try again. i can't test it, so sorry if this doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you just need to provide a placeholder for each of the columns in your union statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS STCount, 0 AS NCCount 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DPoint, RNum 
      FROM ECount
      WHERE DType = 'STR' AND Month(EDate) = '07') AS rows 
UNION SELECT 0, COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DPoint, RNum 
      FROM ECount
      WHERE DType = 'NCD' AND Month(EDate) = '07') AS rows
```

The above doesn't conform to the desired output which was supplied after I added my answer. So, I would suggest you go with one of the other answers (e.g., the one by Richard).

Answer (score 2):

I think you nearly got it use UNION ALL instead of UNION:

```
SELECT DType, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DType From  (Select Distinct DPoint, RNum From
    ECount  Where DType = 'STR' and Month(EDate) = '07') as rows 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DType From  (Select Distinct DPoint, RNum From
    ECount  Where DType = 'NCD' and Month(EDate) = '07') as rows
)
GROUP BY DType
ORDER BY DType
```

for more on UNION a[UNION ALL VS. UNION](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1387/union-vs-union-all-in-sql-server/)

Comment: What kind of struggle?  Do you have some error message or do you get different result than you expected?  Need more information for helping you.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(x.[STR]) as STCount, sum(x.[NCD]) as NCCount
from ECount  
pivot (count(DType) for DTypein ([NCD], [STR])) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

A more practical approach might be selecting each type of count as a separate record and use grouping:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*) AS TypeCount,
   Dtype
FROM ECount
WHERE Dtype IN ('STR', 'NCD')
  AND MONTH(Edate) = '07'
GROUP BY Dtype;
```

Comment: This would be fine but i need the Distinct selection of DPoint, RNum to get the correct count.